# Getting Instantiation error while retrieving mongo documents

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to read the Mongo document with abstract class implementation from springboot application.

```
@Document(collection = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private String id;    
    @Field
    private EmployeeType type;
    ... 
}

public abstract class EmployeeType {

}

public class Employee extends EmployeeType {

private List<String> name;
..
...

}

public class Contract extends EmployeeType {

private String name;
...
....

}
```

---

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is("12"));
Employee employee = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Employee.class);
```

When I am extracting records from MongoDB with mongo template it gives below error

**java.lang.InstantiationError: EmployeeType**

Can somebody help me here?

Comment: Please show how your data actually looks inside mongo db first.

Comment: {
    "_id": "12",
    "type": [{
        "tech1",
  "tech2"
    }],
    
    "_class": "..Employee"
}


    "_id": "13",
    "type": {
        "tech1"  
    },
    
    "_class": "..Employee"
}